# Creating on object accessible by several methods

Tags: python

When I open a `netcdf` file with `xarray` (see [https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/index.html]) :

```
dd = xarray.open_dataset (file)
```

I obtain an object that can be accessed by two methods :

```
dd.var    # Like a namespace or class
dd['var'] # Like a dictionary
```

I'm looking to create an object, class or whatever, that can be accessed in the same way, using any of these two methods.

`xarray` shows that such objects are feasible. But how ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735399/how-to-implement-the-getitem-dunder-method-in-python-to-get-attribute-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `__getitem__` dunder method. You can implement this method in your class to return the attributes using square bracket access method.

A sample implementation can be as following:

```py
class T:
    attr1 = 10
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)
```

When we create an instance of class `T`, we can access `attr1` by using `dot` operator or by using square brackets.

```py
>>> t = T()
>>> t.attr1
10
>>> t['attr1']
10
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here are two effective approaches you can use:**

1. Combining `collections.namedtuple` and `collections.OrderedDict`:

This approach provides a straightforward and efficient way to create a data structure that combines the namespace-like features of a `namedtuple` with the dictionary-like access of an `OrderedDict` using `__new__`.

```
import collections

class FlexibleDataContainer(collections.namedtuple('FlexibleDataContainer', 'keys')):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, keys, **kwargs):
        # Ensure keys are in order and unique
        keys = list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(keys))  
        cls._instance = super().__new__(cls, keys)
        cls._instance._data = collections.OrderedDict((key, kwargs[key]) for key in keys)
        return cls._instance

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._data:
            return self._data[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f"Attribute {name} not found")

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._data[key]

# Create an instance:

dd = FlexibleDataContainer({'var1': 'A', 'var2': 10, 'data3': [1, 2, 3]})

# Access using dot notation:

print(dd.var1)      # Output: A

print(dd.data3)     # Output: [1, 2, 3]

# Access using dictionary notation:

print(dd['var2'])   # Output: 10
```

2. Creating a Custom Class with `__getattr__` and `__getitem__`:

This approach offers more flexibility and customization down the road.

```
class FlexibleDataContainer:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._data:
            return self._data[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f"Attribute {name} not found")

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._data[key]

# Create an instance:

dd = FlexibleDataContainer({'var1': 'A', 'var2': 10, 'data3': [1, 2, 3]})

# Access using dot notation:

print(dd.var1)      # Output: A

print(dd.data3)     # Output: [1, 2, 3]

# Access using dictionary notation:

print(dd['var2'])   # Output: 10
```

**Key Points:**

Ordering of Members: If you need to guarantee the order of the elements, use collections.OrderedDict as the internal data storage in both methods.
Flexibility: The second method with a custom class gives you more control over how the object behaves, allowing you to add custom logic or validation to the attribute and dictionary-like access.

**Choose the method that best suits your needs:**

If you just need a simple and efficient object with dual access methods, the namedtuple/OrderedDict approach is a good choice.
If you require more customization or control over the object's behavior, the custom class method is more suitable.